# Acknowledging remaining messages for consumer in RabbitMQ

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq

I have a queue and 3 consumers bind to the queue. Each consumer has a prefetch_count of 250(or say X) and manual acknowledgement is done  prefetch_count(X)/2(i.e 125) messages - meaning consumer manually acknowledges 125 messages in a single go (which helps to reduce round-trip time and hence increases performance). Everything is working fine as expected but the only issue arises when there are no new messages in the queue and the consumers have some unacknowledged messages whose count is less 125.

As the acknowledgement is only sent when the count is 125, these unacknowledged messages keeps requeuing. How can I solve this ?

How can I know that my consumer has no new messages to process and can acknowledge all the remaining messages waiting to be acknowledged.

Comment: Is there some performance concern with acknowledging 1-2 instead of 125 at a time? I have never found that a pre-fetch > 2 to be beneficial. Alternatively, what is stopping you from using a timer to trigger the ack?

Comment: Yes. recommended prefetch count is around 300. And manual acknowledgement of bulk messages improves performance. Read, really interesting: http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/09/24/sizing-your-rabbits/

Comment: Timer will trigger a ack at a random time. I only want to acknowledge when my task is complete.

Comment: @theMayer Thanks for the edit and comment. I will highly value your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your scenario correctly, it sounds as though you have a series of messages that get published all at once, and then you process them in batches of 250 at a time until you have none left.  The problem is, that if you don't have a number of messages that is divisible by 125, then your final batch never gets acknowledged.  Clearly this is a logical problem, but it sounds like you are wondering if there is an easy way to deal with it.

Your question "How can I know that my consumer has no new messages to process?" is based upon a premise which RabbitMQ does not support -- namely, the "end" of a sequence of messages.  RabbitMQ consumers expect to continue to receive messages indefinitely, so from their perspective, there is no such thing as "done."

Thus, any such concept must be implemented elsewhere, higher up in your application logic.  Here are some options for you to consider:

1. If you know in advance how many messages will be processed, then send that count first and store. Send the final ack once you have processed that number (assuming no duplicates were processed).
2. Monitor the in-memory collection at the consumer (all pre-fetched messages reside here until they are actually processed). When it drops below 125, you know that you have a batch size less than that.
3. Similar to #1, send a special "last message" that the consumer can receive and know to acknowledge upon receipt.

**Caveat:** I would argue that you have some deeper design problem going on that is leading down the path where it would ever be desirable to do this in the first place. Each message should be 100% independent of any other message. If that assumption is violated, you will have a very fragile system.

Comment: Thank you @theMayer . One of the thing I want to clarify is we do not publish everything at once. There is continous stream of messages being published, not batch publishing. There are consumers who manually acknowledges each message after completing a desired task attached to that message. This works beautifully. But improve our performance more. We wanted to acknowledge messages in bulk not one by one.  Thats is also a recommendation in the article I have shared  with you. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: 125 messages still seems like a lot to me, but I guess I don't understand why you can't just wait until eventually 125 messages pile up? Or add a pre-set window/interval of time? I don't believe any other option is possible.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from acknowledging more frequently. This will not affect the performance of processing or delivering